# Boost dll unload() deadlock with mingw 4.9.2 windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, boost, dll

I'd like to load a dll instance, resolve it's export symbols and use it inside a wrapper class. Here is the way I do it :

```
WrapperImpl::WrapperImpl( const std::string& libName )
{
   boost::filesystem::path libPath( boost::filesystem::current_path());
   libPath /= libName;
   m_lib.load(libPath);
   m_lib.unload();
}
```

where `boost::dll::shared_library m_lib;`

I get a deadlock at unload() call, no exceptions have been thrown. I see that dll has been successfully loaded, all the symbols have been resolved, I can call them and get reasonable return codes. But what's wrong with unloading?

I have a single-threaded application ( in fact it's a boost test unit ), boost 1.61, mingw 4.9.2. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: If you get a deadlock, it's usually helpful to run under debugger and see where exactly you have a deadlock - could you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have debug boost libraries at hand :(. Only release ones

Comment: You still can get some backtrace, which might be helpful.

Comment: Well, I've never tried under Windows/Eclipse but here is what I got as a first insight :

ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet() at 0x7c90e514 
ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects() at 0x7c90df4a 
KERNEL32!CreateFileMappingA() at 0x7c809590 
WmiFreeBuffer() at 0x77de8631 
KERNEL32!GetModuleFileNameA() at 0x7c80b729

Is it what you expected?